# Question about Ranks

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that we have the following matrices with entries in $\mathbb{R}$:

$A$  is $n \times n $ and invertible, $B$  is $n \times m$ and  $C$  is $l \times n$ .

we set  $D=CA^{-1}B$.

I want to find the rank of the matrix $\left(\begin{matrix}A&B\\C&D \end{matrix}\right)$.

Should it be $n$ since $D$ depends on $A,B$ and $C$.

My linear algebra is kinda rusty... How can I prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rank is not $n$ in general, it can be larger. Taking $n=k=l=1$ one has examples
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}
 \qquad\text{or}\qquad  \begin{pmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}
$$
both of rank $2$. There is no reason to believe anything non-obvious can be said about the rank in the general case.

For the reformulated question the rank is indeed that of $A$, namely $n$. It clearly cannot be less than that, and on the other hand your matrix can be decomposed as
$$
  \begin{pmatrix}A&B\\C&CA^{-1}B\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}A\\C\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}I_n&A^{-1}B\end{pmatrix},
$$
a product of two matrices of rank$~n$ and therefore of rank at most $n$.

Comment: Thanks... Could you take a look now that I've modified the question?

Comment: @KerryH: done...